# How can i show text from the bottom on hover?

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to fixate the first part of the text and to make it show from the bottom

on the left is the hover that slides from the bottom and on the right is how it should look like in the beginning

Ive put the code I tried to use inside - please take a look
Thank you!

[image]

```css
.container {
  padding: 1em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.image1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  background: rgb(30, 30, 36);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: rgb(246, 244, 234);
  margin: 0px;
}
.middle:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.product-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.product-box:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: all 0.8s linear;
}

.product-box:hover {
  background: rgba(30, 30, 36, 0.6) !important;
}

.product-box:hover .image1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: transparent;
}

.product-box:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeIn-bottom {
  top: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product-box fadeIn-bottom" style="margin-top: 20px;">

    <img src="https://phpmysqlappdiag454.blob.core.windows.net/blob/assets/images/hotelkos/Rectangle 14.png" alt="" data-filename="1.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin-bottom: -40px;" class="image1">

    <div class="middle ">

      <p style="color: #F6F4EA;">Suites</p>

    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please include the html and css you currently have

Comment: In the question, not in the comments and format it correctly using ```

Comment: @Ena please include relevant HTML, CSS code , in your question you have already worked on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,
 Seemingly there are small tweaks that would make it work, but since we don't know we reasonable not going to draft experimental code base.

Comment: Here is the code snippet i tried https://codepen.io/klok028/pen/abjjYvL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is put the relative, i.e. the `product-box` in a `relative position`, then set the `absolute position` to the "title" to which you want to apply the transition. Once this is done, you need to know how to use transitions and how absolute position works. These two things are important enough to make several cool and simple animations so I recommend you to check them out.

```css
.product-box {
  position: relative;
}

.image1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
.title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.product-box:hover .title {
  top: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product-box">
    <div class="title">
      <h4>Suites</h4>
    </div>
    <img src="https://phpmysqlappdiag454.blob.core.windows.net/blob/assets/images/hotelkos/Rectangle 14.png" alt="" data-filename="1.png" class="image1">
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want;

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.image1 {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

.product-box {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F6F4EA;
  background: rgb(30, 30, 36);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  bottom: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.product-box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  transition: all 0.8s linear;
}

.product-box:hover .middle {
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product-box">
    <img src="https://phpmysqlappdiag454.blob.core.windows.net/blob/assets/images/hotelkos/Rectangle 14.png" alt="" class="image1">
    <div class="middle">Suites</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank youu, this gave me a hint in what other way it could be done!